# ui-view layout issue with CSS Angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I can't seem to figure this out. I have an angular app with a header, sidebar, sub header, and content. The content grows automatically, but the when the sidebar is longer than the content, it just does not expand the wrapper container. I have tried a combination of height auto/100%, and I tried using clear both but nothing is happening.

index.html

```
<body>
  <!-- Main HTML gets injected here -->
  <ui-view id="ng_view"></ui-view>
</body>
```

main.html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <tp-header></tp-header>
  <tp-sidebar></tp-sidebar>
  <tp-subheader></tp-subheader>
  <!-- container with class="form" gets injected here -->
  <ui-view id="ng_subview"></ui-view>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html {
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
} 

#wrapper {
    height: auto;
    //min-height: 100%;
    width: 1367px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    //overflow: hidden;
}

#ng_view { height: 100%; }

#ng_subview { display: block; height: 100%; }

/* The style inside the sidebar */
.sidebar {
   width: 343px;
   float: left;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
}

/* .form gets injected into ng_subview */
.form {
   margin: 0px auto;
   width: 1024px;
   height: 100%;
   display: block;
}
```

The sidebar does not push the ng-view and/or wrapper div down when it grows.
I need help with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The primary reason for not pushing content down is because of the sidebar was an absolute positioning. Absolute position takes the element out of the HTML flow, and it will not push content down.

Also, I did some other changes, but it was the absolute positioning was the main cause.